# How to move label

Tags: labels, circuitikz

```
\begin{circuitikz}
   \draw (opamp.out) to [short,-*]   ++(-1.5,0) 
                     to ++(0,1.2) 
                     to[R, l=R]     ++(1.6,0)coordinate[label=](r)
                     to(r)-|(opamp.+); 
\end{circuitikz}
```

I would like to move label to be below,can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the position of the label using `l_` or `l_^`

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[R, l_=$R_1$] ++(2,0) to[R, l^=$R_2$] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please read the manual here: http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#b1

Comment: l_ solved my problem thanks very much :)